# Get started at writing device drivers for FreeBSD

Tags: wifi, drivers, freebsd, network-interface

I just decided to give FreeBSD a try last week and found out that my wireless card (Ralink rt3290) isn't supported.

I am good at C - and I know I have to for this task - and am very fond of Assembly, so I am thinking about writing a driver for ir.
However, I have absolutely **no** experience with driver programming and would like to know your opinion about whether it is feasible or not to do so. I don't know if it helps, but all of the three Linux distros I have installed (Arch, Manjaro and openSUSE) have all the necessary drivers for my machine.

I recently found out that I have a huge interest how the computer and the OSes (mainly *nix) work so I am willing to study deeply any good reading material you can point out for me. Also, if you have any advices and/or experience in the field, I will be grateful for your help.

Thank you very much for your attention and help! I really appreciate it.

Comment: This would be a much better question for one of the FreeBSD mailing lists, probably the best choice would be `freebsd-drivers@freebsd.org`

Comment: [FreeBSD Developer's Handbook](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/developers-handbook/) and [Writing FreeBSD Device Drivers](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/arch-handbook/driverbasics.html)